# Proof: Distributing Divergence operator over cross product of two vectors

Tags: vector-analysis

Given:

$$F = (f_x, f_y, f_z)$$
$$G = (g_x, g_y, g_z)$$

Trying to prove that:

$$\nabla \cdot (F \times G) = G \cdot (\nabla \times F) - F \cdot (\nabla \times G)$$

So I start with:

$$\nabla \cdot (F \times G)$$

$$\nabla \cdot (F \times G) =  \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial{x}},\ \ \ \frac{\partial}{\partial{y}},\ \ \ \frac{\partial}{\partial{z}} \right) \cdot \begin{vmatrix} 
\vec{\textbf{i}} & \vec{\textbf{j}} & \vec{\textbf{k}} \\
f_x & f_y & f_z \\
g_x & g_y & g_z 
\end{vmatrix}$$

$$\nabla \cdot (F \times G) =  \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial{x}},\ \ \ \frac{\partial}{\partial{y}},\ \ \ \frac{\partial}{\partial{z}} \right) \cdot \vec{\textbf{i}} \begin{vmatrix}
f_y & f_z \\
g_y & g_z 
\end{vmatrix} + \vec{\textbf{j}} \begin{vmatrix}
f_x & f_z \\
g_x & g_z 
\end{vmatrix} + \vec{\textbf{k}} \begin{vmatrix}
f_x & f_y \\
g_x & g_y 
\end{vmatrix}$$

$$\nabla \cdot (F \times G) =  \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial{x}} \begin{vmatrix}
f_y & f_z \\
g_y & g_z 
\end{vmatrix},\ \ \ \frac{\partial}{\partial{y}}\begin{vmatrix}
f_x & f_z \\
g_x & g_z 
\end{vmatrix},\ \ \ \frac{\partial}{\partial{z}}\begin{vmatrix}
f_x & f_y \\
g_x & g_y 
\end{vmatrix} \right)$$

$$\nabla \cdot (F \times G) =  \frac{\partial}{\partial{x}}(f_y g_z - f_z g_y) - \frac{\partial}{\partial{y}}(f_x g_z - f_z g_x) + \frac{\partial}{\partial{z}}(f_x g_y - f_y g_x)
$$

At this point, I get stuck in the proof...

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** To get past this point, apply the product rule for partial derivatives.  For example:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial{x}}(f_y g_z) = \frac{\partial{f_y}}{\partial{x}} g_z + f_y \frac{\partial{g_y}}{\partial{x}}$$